# Verb tense following "could have" in future

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, syntactic-analysis, time

Hello dear forum members, 
The other day, as I was trying to formulate an acceptable sentence to express my frustration with someone about forcing me to leave the house for the train station extremely early, even though the train was due to leave in 30 minutes or more, I found myself in a bit of a pickle, because I didn't seem to be able to decide which verb tense would be most suitable in the following sentence.

I could've come a couple of minutes before the train leaves/left.
(I am already at the train station, but it's still a long time before the train comes.)

I've been trying to forget about this, considering the fact that it happened ages ago and it's been eating away at my brain ever since that day, but the stubborn language obsessed side of me just won't leave me in peace.
Also, as a side note I have to mention that my English has sadly gotten extremely rusty, since I haven't used it as much as I would've liked to since moving to the country that I live in now, so it could just be that I'm overcomplicating something simple.

Some alternatives that I came up with after having a good and long think about this are the following sentences:

I could've come later so I wouldn't have to wait here for this long.

I could've come only in time to catch the train.

I don't see why I had to get here so early when the train won't even be here before xx:xx .

I'd very much appreciate an answer.
cheers

Comment: Were it me, I'd say either, "I could have left the house much later and still been on time" or "I could have arrived [at the station] later and still had plenty of time [before the train left]."

Comment: These are both pretty good suggestions, but isn't there any way to make the first sentence I mentioned work? I mean, I can think of a few other scenarios where "could have" could be used to talk about a possibility in the future, such as : We could have discussed this after we ate dinner. ( we are discussing this matter right now and having dinner at the same time, but discussing it after eating dinner would've been a better idea.) @MDHunter

Comment: I would definitely say: I could've come later so ***I wouldn't have had*** to wait for so long. Why are you asking about so many sentences? By the way, there is no future here at all. It's all conditional.

Comment: I could have left much later and still made it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence:

'I could've come later so I wouldn't have to wait here for this long.'

Isn't quite right. I would word it as:

'I could've come later so I wouldn't have had to have waited here for so long!'

That's how I would say it.

I changed 'this long' to 'so long' - because it emphasises the length - which is the main point of your sentence - 'the how long' you had to wait. And makes it in the past - the wait is over.

(You could leave it as 'this' - in which case, you yourself are in the present tense - giving the sense that you are exclaiming this - right now! - perhaps to a friend who has just shown up).

Whereas with 'so' - you are reporting completed events, after the fact.

And I put the conditional 'wouldn't have had to' because that tells us your condition was 'forced'. You 'had to' do something. You 'had to' - wait.

The 'have waited' is past continuous - it tells us your wait... went on for a time.

If you use -so long - then the wait happened and is over.
If you use -this long - then the wait was going on and is concluding - right now, or has gone on up to right now - the moment of your speaking.

I hope that helps your poor brain! It is a complicated sentence construction.

Your first sentence could be reworded correctly as:

I could've come just a couple of minutes before the train left!

I added the 'just' to emphasise the difference between the short wait - and your actual, long one.

I added the (optional) exclamation mark for clarity - as what is being described or hoped for, was not actually what occurred (hence - 'surprise!').

Another option (exclamation!):

'If only I'd've come just a few minutes before the train left!'

Comment: Well , first of all, thanks @Jelila for your elaborate response. It's helpful in many ways, however one thing that I can't quite wrap my head around is why you changed " wouldn't " to "wouldn't have had" in the first sentence. Perhaps I wasn't completely clear with regards to the scenario. let's say I was on the phone with the person who had forced me to go to the train station early, still waiting for the train. Since the waiting is still taking place and not over yet, would it be appropriate to use "wouldn't have had" ?

Comment: Well it is an extensive question!  No, because you are talking about the 'waiting' that you have already done. Or the waiting that you will have to 'have done' before the train arrives.

Comment: Fair enough. One more question and then I'm done. :-) I just want to double check that this sentence "I could've come just a couple of minutes before the train left!"  is what you'd have said while you were at the train station and not when talking about those past events in present.

Comment: Yes Ana! Exactly. That one works for that, as is. @Ana

Comment: Cool! glad if it helped!

Comment: @Ana I would look for a way to express my idea with less words. I'd have said, "I could've come just before the train was due," As encouragement, may I say I wasn't sure you were not a native speaker until your question said so. :)

Comment: @Ross Murray. I agree. Dropping the habit of being very detailed when it comes to languages would probably make my life a whole lot easier & thanks by the way for the encouragement. I did go to an English school, but as with all other skills, language skills kind of go down the drain when you don't use them for a while or in my case for a couple of years .

Comment: Well, if you really wanted to be simple you could've said 'why didn't you bloody well tell me the right time to get here!' And... 'I've been waiting here bloody ages for you, freezing my arse off!' (Colloquial). Note: this approach may relieve headaches).

Comment: @Jelila hahaha. Well the thing is, I wasn't waiting for anyone. I was just waiting for the train, but my paranoid friend forced me to leave the house way earlier than was necessary so that I wouldn't miss the train , which I didn't miss, cos I got to the train station 30 minutes earlier than I had to. :-))

Comment: Ha ha! Too bad...

Comment: 'I could've come later so I wouldn't have had to wait here for so long!' is much lighter and standard. "would  have had to have waited" is too much and not the right idea in any case.

Comment: ‘to wait here’ doesn’t convey the sense of the waiting going on for a long time. I would not say the phrase the way that you have put it, @Lambie. ‘Wouldn’t have had to have waited’ is what I would naturally say, as a native English speaker, from England... I would use ‘to wait here’ if it was just a 5 minute wait. And I was still at the bus stop. ‘Wouldn’t have had to have waited’ is exactly what I would say, and what sounds the most natural, and idiomatic, phrase to me. Lighter is what sense? Using less words? There is, as yet, no tax on using words.

Comment: @Jelila  I am not convinced that your preference for "to have waited" is only BrE.

Comment: I had the feeling, @Lambie, that the ‘to wait’ might sound ok in colloquial or casual American English, but that it was maybe a slightly lazy way of speaking and not strictly correct. But I’m from the UK so I can’t tell you for sure. In English I might exclaim ‘I had to wait for ages!’ though.

Comment: @Jelila I really don't think invoking BrE here works.  As for: "I would have had to wait" being less correct than "I would have had to have waited", I find it specious. But not here: "I would have had to have gone if I had wanted to see him that evening." This is not a casual American thing versus a British thing.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I'm inclined to agree with @Lambie: the issue the speaker is complaining about is "I had to wait", not "I had to have waited", so it becomes "I would have had to wait". The other form would be appropriate in a context such as "I tried to get a refund for my ticket, but to be eligible I would have had to have waited over an hour for the train".